# jQuery draggable Snap to Center while dragging

Tags: jquery-ui, draggable

I have draggable object in the page, and it has snap setting for the region.

```
<div class="drag-bound">
  <div id="obj"></div>
</div>

$('#obj').draggable({
  snap: ".drag-bound",
  snapTolerance: 5
})
```

So now if `$('#obj')` is dragged near the border of `".drag-bound"`, it gets snapped there.

The problem is I want `$('#obj')` is snapped to the center of the `".drag-bound"`, too.

Is there any good idea how to make it happen?

Should I make custom code inside of `drag` event handler?

Is there any good and easy option inside of it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, so far from my investigation, there seems not to be a good option to accomplish my purpose.

I have made custom code inside of drag event handler like following:

```
       fn.branding.$resizable.draggable({

          snap: ".resize-bound",
          snapTolerance: 5,

          drag: function(event, ui) {

            var ui_w = ui.helper.width();
            var ui_h = ui.helper.height();
            var margin = $(this).draggable("option", "snapTolerance");

            /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
            // do custom snapping here
            //
            if (!(Math.abs((ui.position.left + (ui_w)/2) - (fn.branding.modal_preview_width/2)) > 2 * margin)) {
              ui.position.left = Math.round((fn.branding.modal_preview_width - ui_w)/2);
            }

            if (!(Math.abs((ui.position.top + (ui_h)/2) - (fn.branding.modal_preview_height/2)) > 2 * margin)) {
              ui.position.top = Math.round((fn.branding.modal_preview_height - ui_h)/2);
            }

          });
```

Comment: This is precisely what I am trying to accomplish. However, I am unsure what fn.branding.modal_preview_height is.  Can you provide the html please. I am assuming that fn.branding is some html element that is being dragged and resized, but the modal_preview_height threw me off.  Thanks